# KnockoutJS - Updating ViewModel OnChange of textbox value instead of OnBlur Options

Tags: knockout.js

I'm pretty new to KnockoutJS and I love what I've seen so far. 
Currently, when an observable property of the View Model is bound to 
the text property of the text box (input type=text), the ViewModel 
gets updated only on the blur event of the textbox. Is there a way to 
update the View Model on the change event of the textbox? I tried 
creating a custom binding handler on wiring up the change event 
handler on the text box in the "init", but it somehow did not work. Is 
this the correct to achieve this goal? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also use a 'value' binding and add the `valueUpdate` binding attribute to specify when to update your control:

See here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

```
<p>Your value: <input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>You have typed: <span data-bind="text: someValue"></span></p> <!-- updates in real-time     -->

<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {
    someValue: ko.observable("edit me")
};
</script>
```

Comment: Be careful as this will not guarantee 100% update, e.g. if a user pastes using a context menu, this won't work.

Answer (score 7):

Above is not work while copy paste from mouse so you need to pass events in valueUpdate.
like..

```
<p>Your value: <input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']" /></p>
```

Try here http://jsfiddle.net/uJCQq/4/

Comment: Thanks, helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official Knockout.js documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html):

> **Getting value updates instantly from inputs**: If you are trying to bind an  or  to get instant updates to your viewmodel, use the [textInput binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html). It has better support for browser edge cases than any combination of valueUpdate options.