# Update knockout.js view-model immediately after textbox value changes

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js

How to make knockout.js update view-model immediately after text input value changes? The problem is that update triggers only when field loose focus.

From [knockout.js documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html):

> "afterkeydown" is the best choice if you want to
>   keep your view model updated in real-time.

I don't found this helpful. In my system I have field called user token. Therefore users often paste token using mouse.

So how to make knockout.js updates it's model immediately for every text change in text field.

Comment: at the very least, it would have to get focused in order for them to paste the token in right?  So maybe have a focus event handler run as a backup.  Or else there is always just onchange

Comment: agreed, once pasted and tab out/lose focus onchange or using jquerys change() function would be more suitable than checking for each key entry

Answer (score 1):

As you alluded to in your question, this is controlled by the [`valueUpdate` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).

`input` is the recommended value for this, if you only need to support "modern browsers." "Non-modern browers" basically means IE8 and earlier. From the docs:

> Of [all the `valueUpdate`] options, `input` is the best choice if you want to keep your
>   view model updated in real-time, and you only need to support
>   reasonably modern browsers such as IE 9+ (whereas "afterkeydown" is a
>   good choice for older browsers). For example:

```
<p>Your value: <input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'input'" /></p>
<p>You have typed: <span data-bind="text: someValue"></span></p> <!-- updates in real-time -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        someValue: ko.observable("edit me")
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

at the very least, it would have to get focused in order for them to paste the token in right? So maybe have a focus event handler run as a backup.

Or else there is always just onchange.

Here is a SO post on using onchange in knockout.js, since I have personally never used it myself.
[KnockoutJS - Updating ViewModel OnChange of textbox value instead of OnBlur Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604961/knockoutjs-updating-viewmodel-onchange-of-textbox-value-instead-of-onblur-opti)

Comment: or i guess technically the answer was to use a value binding.